# hiding a column in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to hide a column in a gridview. I use the following code;

```
dgvTekleme.Columns[1].Visible = false;
```

but this does not work. (may be it does not work because of using that column in the code)
Is there any solution to hide a column in code-behind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this manually.....
goto asp:gridview tag and in gridview tag set autogeneratecolumn="false"
if you don't want to display some column just don't write that column....
for example if you don't want to display prodId column just erase that line....
and write manually for displaying data like!!!!!!!!!!

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="ProdID" DataField="prodid" ReadOnly="true" />
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="ProdName" DataField="ProdName" />
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Quantity" DataField="quantity" />
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="SupplierID" DataField="SupplierId" />
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="StockLvl" DataField="stocklevel" />
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="MinStockLvl" DataField="minstocklevel" />
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="CostPrice" DataField="costprice" />
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="SalesPrice" DataField="saleprice" />
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Loc" DataField="location" />
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="ProdCode" DataField="prodtypecode" />
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true"  ShowDeleteButton="true" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

or you can check this link:
[How to hide columns in an ASP.NET GridView with auto-generated columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091457/how-to-hide-columns-in-an-asp-net-gridview-with-auto-generated-columns)

Comment: I fill gridview dynamically with sql query and I dont wnat to erade the column because I use it. I want just to not show it

Comment: check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091457/how-to-hide-columns-in-an-asp-net-gridview-with-auto-generated-columns