# How do I make several gridview columns invisible dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using

```
e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
```

to make a single column invisible. It works but when I try to add another like so:

```
e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false; 
e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false; //i tried listing all and still got the out of range error
```

I get the error `Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index`

I am using the commands in the Gridview's `RowDataBound` Event and starting from 0 the gridview has 12 columns

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to examine the data you are binding the gridview to at runtime?  Also, is your gridview set to autogeneratecolumns = true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take into account that a `GridView` has some rows that are not data (pager, footer, etc).

I'd say you should have something like this so you only apply hiding logic to `DataRow` elements.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false; 
    e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false;
}
```

To see all row types check [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolrowtype.aspx).

Comment: I believe if you are hiding columns, you don't need to do it in the DataRow section.  Not sure but I think the column count should be consistent in the header and data.

Answer (score 1):

If you have autogeneratecolumns = true for your Gridview you may need to put the code into the `RowCreated` event instead of the `RowDataBound` event.

Here is a similar answer:  [How To Hide Columns with auto-generated columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091457/how-to-hide-columns-in-an-asp-net-gridview-with-auto-generated-columns)