# How to make gridview column visible true or false dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using GridView in asp.net like this:

```
    mygrid.DataSource = dTable;       
    mygrid.DataBind();

    if (mygrid.Columns.Count > 1)
    {
        mygrid.Columns[2].Visible = false;
    }
```

my grid view code is as follows

```
    <asp:GridView ID="mygrid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
       onpageindexchanging="mygrid_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="15" 
       PersistedSelection="true"  
       ondatabound="mygrid_DataBound">
       <Columns>
           <asp:TemplateField>
           <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:HyperLink ID="Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Value", "~/myweppage.aspx?Id=M{0}") %>' />
           </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField> 
       </Columns>           
       <PagerSettings PageButtonCount="4" />


   </asp:GridView>
```

Here I am not able to set `visible=false`.

I tried with the following answer

[How do I make several gridview columns invisible dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662615/how-do-i-make-several-gridview-columns-invisible-dynamically)

I am not finding `datarow` event in Visual Studio 2010. Can anyone help me to set the column visible property?

my Column structure of data table is

column[0] is `Value` column then 4 other columns are there.

my Column structure of Grid view is
column[0] is `link field`
column[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662615/how-do-i-make-several-gridview-columns-invisible-dynamically) is `Value field from Dtable`
4 other columns

Comment: if i am not putting inside the if condition then object reference not set error its giving. if i put inside if condition contol is not coming.

Comment: have you used `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` for gridview?

Comment: @Bhavesh Kachhadiya if i set AutoGenerateColumns="false"  ptoperty then only on colum is visible. columns which are coming from data table are not visible. again same problem column count> 1 condition fails.

Comment: I have edited answer it will work perfect for you.Please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is perfect solution for dynamically generated columns in gridview

Please try this :

```
int indexOfColumn = 1; //Note : Index will start with 0 so set this value accordingly
protected void mygrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.Cells.Count > indexOfColumn)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[indexOfColumn].Visible = false;
    } 
}
```

For .aspx page edit gridview tag as follow :

```
 <asp:GridView ID="mygrid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
       onpageindexchanging="mygrid_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="15" 
       PersistedSelection="true"  
       ondatabound="mygrid_DataBound"
       OnRowDataBound="mygrid_RowDataBound">
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simple answer. Create css as below

```
.classHide{ display:none }
```

then instead of `column.visible = false`, just assign `classHide` CSS class to the column.

e.g.

```
grdRole.Columns(0).ItemStyle.CssClass = "classHide"
    grdRole.Columns(0).HeaderStyle.CssClass = "classHide"
```

Comment: that column only not getting to assign.object reference not set error its giving

Comment: mygrid.Columns[2].cssClass="classHide"

Comment: Property cssClass not found

Comment: It's working. This is the best answer really because what if you want to hide a column and yet still have access to the controls in it? In other words, you don't want to remove it entirely from the DOM. If you do and don't care, then .Visible = false is enough

Comment: @@Indranil.Bharambe thank u...so much...by using css class....i can easily get the column on client side...

Answer (score 2):

**strong text**Try to make use of the event `ItemDataBound` event and try the following syntax to hide the column dynamically:

```
   mygrid.Columns[1].Visible = false           //(Example)
```

**Column count for a datatable starts from 0 not from 1 . so if it is the second column , you want to hide, index should be 1.**

Hope this helps..

Comment: @Raghuveera..you can also make use of the event..Pre Render to hide columns

Comment: Giving error like this       Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: @Raghuveera.what is the value of the index , you have given ?

Comment: 2 because in data table it is 2nd column.

Comment: @Raghuveera..if that does not work..can you please try using Prerender and other thing is are you setting AutogenerateColumns=False or not?

Comment: It should be 1 if its the second column in the database, beacause the column count for the data table starts from 0 not from 1.

Comment: No i got you point. but not working i will give you the coloumn structure wait.

Comment: see at the end of my question i specified column indexes

Answer (score 2):

right Click on gridview and select Properties then select Events you will find there RowDataBound Double Click on it and in Row data bound write this

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < YourGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    (YourGrid.Columns[2]).Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: Thanks @ Robert Columbia